# How do I make the brackets $\{\}$ appear automatically in a function that I personally defined?

Tags: math-mode, overleaf, automation, function

I'm currently writing a big paper and I defined a lot of function to save time, most function are in the math mode (I don't really know if that's important).

My question, that while using overleaf, the system recommends the function that I defined but won't put atomically the brackets {} after the function and I have functions where 7 pairs of {} should appear in order to correctly write the expression.

Is it possible to make them appear automatically ? Thanks in advance for your answer. A small example is defining the ket function (I know it already exists in the package physics but it's just an example).

```
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\mathinner{ | #1 \rangle }}
```

Overleaf already recommends this function to me when I type \k for example but when I choose this function only this part appears \ket and I want it to show \ket{}. It's really a question that would allow me to go so much faster writing the paper.

Comment: I suggest that you give an example, with code, of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think you're (1) trying to have the `{}` appear in the tex source as part of Overleaf's autocomplete, but it could be you're (2) wanting the output to have `{}` present but can't quite get to happen.  Could you confirm that it's (1) and not (2)?

Comment: it's the first one (1), I want them to appear in the tex source.